# I am getting this error when i try to use bootstrap-vue in vuejs application, How to resolve this

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-vue

This is the main.js file

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

createApp(App).use(BootstrapVue).mount('#app')
```

This is the error

```
export 'default' (reexported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue' (possible exports:    BaseTransition, Comment, EffectScope, Fragment, KeepAlive, ReactiveEffect, Static, Suspense, Teleport, Text, Transition, TransitionGroup, VueElement, assertNumber, callWithAsyncErrorHandling, callWithErrorHandling, camelize, capitalize, cloneVNode, compatUtils, compile, computed, createApp, createBlock, createCommentVNode, createElementBlock, createElementVNode, createHydrationRenderer, createPropsRestProxy, createRenderer, createSSRApp, createSlots, createStaticVNode, createTextVNode, createVNode, customRef, defineAsyncComponent, defineComponent, defineCustomElement, defineEmits, defineExpose, defineProps, defineSSRCustomElement, devtools, effect, effectScope, getCurrentInstance, getCurrentScope, getTransitionRawChildren, guardReactiveProps, h, handleError, hydrate, initCustomFormatter, initDirectivesForSSR, inject, isMemoSame, isProxy, isReactive, isReadonly, isRef, isRuntimeOnly, isShallow, isVNode, markRaw, mergeDefaults, mergeProps, nextTick, normalizeClass, normalizeProps, normalizeStyle, onActivated, onBeforeMount, onBeforeUnmount, onBeforeUpdate, onDeactivated, onErrorCaptured, onMounted, onRenderTracked, onRenderTriggered, onScopeDispose, onServerPrefetch, onUnmounted, onUpdated, openBlock, popScopeId, provide, proxyRefs, pushScopeId, queuePostFlushCb, reactive, readonly, ref, registerRuntimeCompiler, render, renderList, renderSlot, resolveComponent, resolveDirective, resolveDynamicComponent, resolveFilter, resolveTransitionHooks, setBlockTracking, setDevtoolsHook, setTransitionHooks, shallowReactive, shallowReadonly, shallowRef, ssrContextKey, ssrUtils, stop, toDisplayString, toHandlerKey, toHandlers, toRaw, toRef, toRefs, transformVNodeArgs, triggerRef, unref, useAttrs, useCssModule, useCssVars, useSSRContext, useSlots, useTransitionState, vModelCheckbox, vModelDynamic, vModelRadio, vModelSelect, vModelText, vShow, version, warn, watch, watchEffect, watchPostEffect, watchSyncEffect, withAsyncContext, withCtx, withDefaults, withDirectives, withKeys, withMemo, withModifiers, withScopeId)`your text`
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `vue-bootstrap` with Vue 3, but at the moment, it only works with the migration build, not Vue 3 itself. Have a look at the [documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/vue3)